# Is there any another method for adjusting transverse field? (D'wave)

Tags: d-wave, ising-model

By using QUBO formula, I can't take in Transverse field equation

I was tried using of annealing schedule but it was failed .

Is there any another method for adjusting transverse field?

(I want to get solution for transverse field isingmodel)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a literature search on arXive? Something like https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.13660.pdf might point you in the right direction.